# iOS: How to "Refresh" a UIViewController after Popping its Child UIViewController?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, nsuserdefaults, setneedsdisplay

In my app I'm using UINavigationController. I have a "parent" UIViewController and a "child" UIViewController running on the stack. The user can do some settings on the child that are later on suppose to affect the parent. I use NSUserDefaults to save and retrieve the data, and it seems to be working fine according to the NSLog.

What I'm not clear about is how am I supposed to "refresh" the data once I come back from the child.

Let me be more specific: In the child there is a "Back" button that does  popViewControllerAnimated and then we go back to the parent. I want to re-run all the method I have in viewDidLoad so the parent view fields are set with the changes I got from the NSUserDefaults data.

1. Where in the parent methods am I supposed to tell the view to "refresh"?
2. How do I do this refresh action? should I call viewDidLoad again? I read about something called setNeedsDisplay, if that is the thing I should use, what is the syntax (is it "[self. view setNeedsDisplay]" or something else)?

Can anyone direct and elaborate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at **[NSNotification](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html)** - thats an easy way to send updates from one part of your code to another is Apple’s built-in NSNotification system.

1. If you have an update you want to send, you call `postNotificationName`. You just give it a unique string you make up (such as “*com.razeware.imagegrabber.imageupdated*”) and an object (such as the ImageInfo that just finished downloading its image).
2. If you want to find out when this update happens, you call `addObserver:selector:name:object`. In our case the ImageListViewController will want to know when this happens so it can reload the appropriate table view cell. A good spot to put this is in viewDidLoad.
3. Don’t forget to call `removeObserver:name:object` when the view gets unloaded. Otherwise, the notification system might try to call a method on an unloaded view (or worse an unallocated object), which would be a bad thing! 
   via Ray Wenderlich [blog](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4295/multithreading-and-grand-central-dispatch-on-ios-for-beginners-tutorial)

Answer (score 2):

You could use `NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification` as a trigger for refreshing the root view controller.

Comment: Is it a method like "- (void) NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification {}" or some line I'm supposed to write someplace (and if so, where)?

Comment: No it is the name of a notification that you can register to using the `NSNotificationCenter` class. Here is a collection of documents on the topic of notifications: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Notifications/

Answer (score 0):

You could also set your ViewController as a delegate to NavigationViewController

```
self.navigationController.delegate = self;
```

Then you will receive delegate calls in method:

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController
       didShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController 
                    animated:(BOOL)animated {
    NSLog(@"Did Show controller %@", viewController);
    // Return from child
    if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[SRPeopleViewController class]]) {
        [self loadData];
    }
```

}

Small drawback - or cost - of this solution is that you will receive more calls than you want, so filtering is necessary.